# What is the listener needed to detect if a JTable cell has been double clicked, and therefore switched to editing mode?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

[image]

When you double click on an editable JTable cell in Swing, the cell goes into a sort of 'editing mode,' a caret appears inside it, and an outline appears around the cell.  My question is, what is the listener I need to use to detect this change into editing mode?

To be clear, I'm not looking for the listener that detects when the value of the cell changes nor am I looking for a double click listener, but rather for the initial switch to editing mode that happens when an editable cell is double clicked.

So, again, what is the listener for this change called? Does it exist, or do I need to modify some other listener?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way is to listen for the property "tableCellEditor". So you can easy get the editor which has been activated/deactivated.

```
table.addPropertyChangeListener("tableCellEditor", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getNewValue() == null) {
            // editing stopped
        } else {
            // editing started
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly the effect I wanted to achieve, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Mouse Listener to table object. In mousePressed() method check click count is 2.This should solve your concern

```
yourTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        JTable table =(JTable) e.getSource();
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        int row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: `if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {` instead of `if (me.getClickCount() == 2) {` ;)

Comment: This could work in some cases, but at the same time sometimes the cells will be editable and sometimes they will not, so a double click doesn't necessarily guarantee that I've entered editing mode. It seems like it would be 'cleaner' to just do an onEditMode listener, but I guess maybe the listener I'm looking for just doesn't exist?

Comment: Just beware, that cell editors can change how and when the become editable, so they don't always become editable with a double click - this means that the could be activated by pressing the enter key or even a single click

Comment: @MadProgrammer is right, it is extremely inconsistent and doesn't really achieve what I want it to

Answer (score 0):

You can use MouseClick event and find how many time click has happen.

sample code

```
jtable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        JTable table =(JTable) me.getSource();
        if (me.getClickCount() == 2) {

         int row = target.getSelectedRow();
         int column = target.getSelectedColumn(); 

         // add your logic here based on which row and column
        }
    }
});
```

This might be helpful. For more detail [click here](http://mycodepage.blogspot.in/2006/09/how-to-create-double-click-event-on.html)

Comment: Just beware, that cell editors can change how and when the become editable, so they don't always become editable with a double click - this means that the could be activated by pressing the enter key or even a single click